# how to display button only for mobile or tablet browsers

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, tablet, mobile-browser

i'm trying to make a responsive theme in word press using twitter bootstrap. In my site there is a sidebar for showing calendar and an appointment form. i need to display a button instead of this if the user uses a mobile or tablet. and if the user uses desktop browser then he/she can see the calendar and form directly in the page itself.how should i do this. any idea??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**bootstrap doc** : http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes

```
<button class="visible-xs visible-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">mybutton</button>
```

Comment: I send you the doc : if you want to don"t show an element on small device then add it the class "hidden-xs" for exemple.

Comment: marked... how can i load a .php file on button click in wordpress?